# Why does the 5-minute edit limit apply to last comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, edits, time-limit

If I make a comment on some answer, and after 5 minutes it is still the last comment, why does the 5-minute edit limit apply to it, when one can very easily just copy its contents, delete the comment, create a new one, paste and edit as one sees fit? <sub>(Other than the potential race condition of someone filing a comment just when you're changing yours)</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because there is no need to. All code necessary to test whether you may or may not edit the comment is not necessary because you can just copy it, as you have said yourself.

You should also consider that others may have read your comment and that they will not get an update notification once you have edited. Allowing to edit your comment if it is the last one also enables spammers to change their on-topic comment later on into a spam comment. And since comments are hard to review, this only makes things worse.

Comment: If MathJax is used in the comment then copying is not easy.

Comment: That is true, but that is another problem that needs fixing. There is already a feature request for comment copying. @OlliNiemitalo